# Execution of python script hangs while executing docker exec command

Tags: python, python-2.7, docker, subprocess

I am new to Docker. I have a python script which does :

1. starts a docker container through:

   ```
   call(["sudo docker run -i -t -d test /bin/sh"],shell=True)
   ```
2. removes a soft link that exists inside the container through the command:

   ```
   call("sudo docker exec -i "+ tag1 +" rm /usr/local/lib/boost_logger",shell=True)
   ```

   where tag1 is my docker container id
3. I copy new files from my centos folders to the docker instance through:

   ```
   call("sudo tar -cv * | sudo docker exec -i "+ tag1 +" tar x -C /usr/local/lib/", shell=True)
   ```
4. I re-create 2 soft links using:

   ```
   call("sudo docker exec -i "+ tag1 +" ln -s /usr/local/lib/libboost_logger.so /usr/local/lib/boost_logger",shell=True)

   call("sudo docker exec -i "+ tag1 +" ln -s /usr/local/lib/libredis_client.so /usr/local/lib/redis_client",shell=True)
   ```
5. Now, I commit the docker image through:

   ```
   dockercommit = ["sudo","docker","commit","-m",'"Building docker instance"',"-a",'"Tejas"',tag1,dockerfilename]

   call(dockercommit)
   ```

The same commands work fine through bash.

The problem I face is after step 2. My script stops execution. It resumes after I manually hit <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> and the rest of the script is executed!

I am running the docker instances on centos running on virtualbox. I have allocated 3 cores and around 10GB base memory.

Also, if there are no docker instances currently running and only the base image present, hitting <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> releases the script immediately.

But in case I have more instances or probably during the second or third iteration of the same script, it takes a longer time for the control to get released.

Comment: is `test` your own image? if so, can you share the Dockerfile?

Comment: what do you think `-i` option does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding user input with `shell=True` is ***strongly discouraged*** as 
mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments):

> **Warning**:  Executing shell commands that incorporate unsanitized input from an untrusted source makes a program vulnerable to shell injection, a serious security flaw which can result in arbitrary command execution. For this reason, the use of shell=True is strongly discouraged in cases where the command string is constructed from external input:

You should instead use [`subprocess.popen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) as mentioned in the note.